# JWT why can I bypass authentication?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, auth0, express-jwt

I am following [this](https://auth0.com/blog/reactjs-authentication-tutorial/) auth0 tutorial for a react/express + jwt webpage.

Everything seems ok. Login/logout, accessing secure page all good.

Except I can bypass the login with a fake token. If I just go to jwt.io and generate a token that hasn't expired yet, I can access the secure page without actually logging in. What am I missing here?

This is the part of the code that handles authentication:

```
./utils/AuthService.js
const ID_TOKEN_KEY = 'id_token';
const ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = 'access_token';

const CLIENT_ID = 'auht0 client id';
const CLIENT_DOMAIN = 'foo.eu.auth0.com';
const REDIRECT = 'http://localhost:3000/callback';
const SCOPE = 'openid profile ';
const AUDIENCE = 'https://foo.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/';

var auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
  clientID: CLIENT_ID,
  domain: CLIENT_DOMAIN
});

export function login() {
  auth.authorize({
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    redirectUri: REDIRECT,
    audience: AUDIENCE,
    scope: SCOPE
  });
}

export function logout() {
  clearIdToken();
  clearAccessToken();
  browserHistory.push('/');
}

export function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!isLoggedIn()) {
    replace({pathname: '/'});
  }
}

export function getIdToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem(ID_TOKEN_KEY);
}

export function getAccessToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
}

function clearIdToken() {
  localStorage.removeItem(ID_TOKEN_KEY);
}

function clearAccessToken() {
  localStorage.removeItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
}

// Helper function that will allow us to extract the access_token and id_token
function getParameterByName(name) {
  let match = RegExp('[#&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.hash);
  return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

// Get and store access_token in local storage
export function setAccessToken() {
  let accessToken = getParameterByName('access_token');
  localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, accessToken);
}

// Get and store id_token in local storage
export function setIdToken() {
  let idToken = getParameterByName('id_token');
  localStorage.setItem(ID_TOKEN_KEY, idToken);
}

export function isLoggedIn() {
  const idToken = getIdToken();
  return !!idToken && !isTokenExpired(idToken);
}

function getTokenExpirationDate(encodedToken) {
  const token = decode(encodedToken);
  if (!token.exp) { return null; }

  const date = new Date(0);
  date.setUTCSeconds(token.exp);

  return date;
}

function isTokenExpired(token) {
  const expirationDate = getTokenExpirationDate(token);
  return expirationDate < new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you've posted just stores / retrieves the token from the local storage.
The authentication itself is handled on the server side

```
  secret: jwks.expressJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        // YOUR-AUTH0-DOMAIN name e.g prosper.auth0.com
        jwksUri: "https://{YOUR-AUTH0-DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json"
    }),
    // This is the identifier we set when we created the API
    audience: '{YOUR-API-AUDIENCE-ATTRIBUTE}',
    issuer: '{YOUR-AUTH0-DOMAIN}',
    algorithms: ['RS256']
});
```

The sever-side funtionality MUST check the JWT token signature. Without the private key you won't be able to generate a valid signature of the JWT token.

If you really can bypass the authentication, it means the server has serious security issue (the signature is not properly validated). Maybe for test/demo services it is not implemented.

Comment: So no info will be retrieved from the server but the react/front-end secure page is still accessible and any content that's not sent by the server is displayed ...

Comment: The token is intended only to access the backend services and optionally provide basic user information (claims) to the client. The client application can be accessible, but it should not be able to retrieve/show/ any user (business) content from the backend without the user beeing authenticated against the backend services.